# Логин в консоль

Tags: c#

Как сделать логин в консоли?

Ну например - заходишь, и тебя просят ввести пароль что бы продолжить. А если не вводишь правильно "еное" кол-во раз пароль - приложение закрывается.

```
            Console.Write("Input a password: ");
            password = Console.ReadLine();

            if (password != "1467")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Incorrect password! Try more!");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                ctzr++;
            }
            else
                ctzr = 1;

        }
        while (password != "123456") && (ctzr != 3));

        if (ctzr == 3)
        {
```

но этот код работает криво и его можно обойти. Хотелось бы по лучше сделать....

Comment: ну туу много может быть вариантов....вы не уточнили многое. Например: где будет хранится правильный пароль, допустимое количество ввода.

Comment: А в чем проблема?

Comment: самое простое, это используя ef, code firset сделать БД, после чего создать класс, который проверит на правильность ввода.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц правил, смотрите, но этот код работает криво и его можно обойти. Хотелось бы по лучше сделать....

Comment: @Zekoy, любой код можно обойти

Comment: как на меня, то хорошая защита, это организовать аутентификацию через свой сервер (`api`)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Я просто хочу сделать вход по паролю в приложение.

Comment: А в чем кривизна и как его можно обойти? Что конкретно вам в нем не нравится? Я не спорю с вашим утверждением, мне он тоже не нравится, но сейчас не об этом.

Comment: @rdorn Это гавнокод, хочётся сделать нормально. И насчёт обойти - там есть баг.

Comment: @Zekoy выносишь этот код в отдельный метод, который вызывается первым при запуске программы и который в случае непрохождения авторизации вызывает метод `Environment.Exit(0)` (т.е. закрывает программу). Если же пользователь проходит авторизацию, то просто выходишь из метода с помощью `return;`. А дальше уже выполняешь свой основной код. Кстати, вместо трех `Console.WriteLine()`. Можно было написать `Console.WriteLine("\nIncorrect password! Try more!\n");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пишите в процедурном стиле. Но ведь можно же писать в ООП стиле, как ни как вы пишите на `C#`!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Напишем лучше так:

Вот входная точка

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Farewell(
        new Attempts(
            new VerboseDiff(
                new Diff(
                    new Password(),
                    new Input()
                    )
                ), 3
            )).Say();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Вот остальные классы, пойдем сверху вниз

```
internal class Farewell
{
    private Attempts attempts;

    public Farewell(Attempts attempts)
    {
        this.attempts = attempts;
    }

    internal void Say()
    {
        if (attempts.UserPassed())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Добро пожаловать!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Извините, ваши попытки закончились!");
        }
    }
}

internal class Attempts
{
    private VerboseDiff verboseDiff;
    private int count;

    public Attempts(VerboseDiff verboseDiff, int count)
    {
        this.verboseDiff = verboseDiff;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public bool UserPassed()
    {
        var result = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (verboseDiff.IsAttemptCorrect())
            {
                result = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

internal class VerboseDiff
{
    private Diff diff;

    public VerboseDiff(Diff diff)
    {
        this.diff = diff;
    }

    public bool IsAttemptCorrect()
    {
        var result = diff.IsInputCorrect();
        if (result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Спасибо.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Извините, пароль неверен.");
        }

        return result;
    }
}

internal class Diff
{
    private Password password;
    private Input input;

    public Diff(Password password, Input input)
    {
        this.password = password;
        this.input = input;
    }

    public bool IsInputCorrect()
    {
        var userInput = input.GetUserInput();
        var currentPassword = password.GetPassword();

        return userInput.Equals(currentPassword);
    }
}

internal class Password
{
    public Password()
    { }

    public string GetPassword()
    {
        return "777";
    }
}

internal class Input
{
    public Input()
    { }

    public string GetUserInput()
    {
        Console.Write("Ваш пароль: ");
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Видите, казалось бы как много классов, но зато какие они простые! Такие классы легко писать и поддерживать.
Идея навеяна этим [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75U9eefFYoU&feature=youtu.be&t=23).

Comment: зачем так сильно усложнять простую процедуру аутентификации и создавать так много классов ? хватит 1-ого класса !!

Comment: @Bulson Спасибо большое ;3